# How to draw a circle and a hexagon with the turtle module?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to use the turtle module and I want to do :

- Draw a red circle, then a yellow circle underneath it and a green circle underneath that.
- to draw a regular hexagon.

can anyone tell me how to work on it?

Comment: This would be a pretty easy task for somebody with experience with these tools, so it would be hard for us to know where to start. Which part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to go about this is to define a circle with parameters and just use what you want. Also since a hexagon is repetitive, you can use a for loop to construct a lot of the sides for it. Here is how I solved it.

```
from turtle import *
setup()
x = 200
# Use your own value
y = 200
# Use your own value

def circles (radius, colour):
    penup()
    pencolor (colour)
    goto (0,radius)
    pendown ()
    setheading (180)
    circle (radius)
    penup()


circles (100, "red")
circles (50, "yellow")
circles (25, "green")

def hexagon (size_length):
    pendown ()
    forward(size_length)
    right (60)

goto (x, y) 
for _ in range (6):
    hexagon (50)             

exitonclick ()
```

With this you don't have to keep defining circle and just add your own parameters and the hexigon can be easily done with a for loop.